# Remove elements from the DOM with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections

I'm getting all the

elements from a menu in order to remove the ones I don't want.

```
let prodMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("productMenu-category");
for (let i = 0; i < prodMenu.length; i++) {
    if(i > 0 && prodMenu[i].innerHTML == prodMenu[i-1].innerHTML){prodMenu[i].style.display = "none";}
}
```

That's what I have now, but I don't want to hide them I want to remove them.
I guess that what I "GET" is something called "collection" that doesn't have any of the function I find for removing it's items.
I can't do "delete prodMenu[i]" or "prodMenu.delete()" nor "prodMenu.splice()" because they are not functions from a "collection"

Comment: Collection is just a collection, it holds the actual DOM nodes found with the selector you gave. Even more - this collection is actually [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is live, it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed (be careful here). And you dont need to modify it directly, you only need to call a [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) method of the elements in this collection.

Comment: Use [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) method of the elements in the collection. Also, use [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a static list of elements. Iterating through a live collection is a bit tricky when removing elemets.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a little bit, Javascript drives me crazy. I need a course or something with a deeper understanding, not just syntax and loops.
Just doing prodMenu[i].remove(); worked, but I couldn't figure that out from ALL the things I've found. Any of you can post an answer, I will set it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection is just a collection, it holds the actual DOM nodes found with the selector you gave. Even more - this collection is actually [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is live, it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed (be careful here). And you dont need to modify it directly, you only need to call a specific [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) method of the elements in this collection.

```
let prodMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("productMenu-category");
for (let i = 0; i < prodMenu.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0 && prodMenu[i].innerHTML == prodMenu[i - 1].innerHTML) {
    prodMenu[i].remove();
  }
}
```